# JavaFX ListCell updateItem executes twice?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I am trying to create custom cells in a ListView , but every time I add a new item, the *updateItem(TextFlow item, Boolean empty)* is executed twice: one time it receives  **null** and **true**, and the second time it does not (**!null** and **false**)

If I do **not** implement the *setCellFactory* method, then I can add the items to the table without problems.

[ListView **without** custom cellFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJNBg.png)

However, when I do implement it, it simply creates 10 empty cells (where is the content?).

[ListView **with** custom cellFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcHaN.png)

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private ListView <TextFlow> console;

private ObservableList<TextFlow> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    console.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<TextFlow>, ListCell<TextFlow>>() {

        @Override
        public ListCell<TextFlow> call(ListView<TextFlow> param) {
            return new ListCell<TextFlow>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(TextFlow item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item != null) {
                        setItem(item);
                        setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: blue;");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Item is null.");
                    }

                }
            };
        }

    });


    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
        Text txt = getStyledText("This is item number " + i + ".");
        TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();
        textFlow.getChildren().add(txt);
        data.add(textFlow);
    }

    console.setItems(data);

}

private Text getStyledText (String inputText) {
    Text text = new Text(inputText);
    text.setFont(new Font("Courier New",12));
    text.setFill(Paint.valueOf("#000000"));
    return text;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateItem` can be called an arbitrary amount of times, different items may be passed and the cell can go from empty to non-empty and the other way round. `ListView` creates about as many cells as you see on screen and fills them with items. E.g. scrolling or modifications of the `items` list or resizing of the `ListView` can result in updates.

For this reason any cell needs to be able to deal with an arbitrary sequence of items (or `null`+empty) being passed to the `updateItem` method.

Furthermore you should avoid invoking `setItem` yourself, since `super.updateItem` does that already. Use `setGraphic` instead, if you want to display the item in the cell:

```
@Override
public ListCell<TextFlow> call(ListView<TextFlow> param) {
    return new ListCell<TextFlow>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(TextFlow item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (item != null) {
                setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: blue;");
                setGraphic(item);
            } else {
                setStyle(null);
                setGraphic(null);
                System.out.println("Item is null.");
            }

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I thought that passing `Nodes` is a bad idea?

Comment: @Sedrick Yes, but I focused on a single issue in my answer.

Comment: @fabian Why is it a bad idea to pass a `Node`?

Comment: @Raccoon a) you can add nodes only once to the scene. If you want to display e.g. the selected node next to the `ListView`, you get into problems. Also it's hard to get any info about the data given an item this way. b) `Node`s are usually big objects and the whole point of virtualizing views is to keep the number of nodes used down to a small number (the visible nodes). If adding the data you'd create the `Node`s from to the items list instead and reuse the node used as geaphic for the cells for different items, you should prefer this to keeping all the nodes in memory at the same time.

Comment: @fabian That makes sense! Thank you.